# Add Page_Init event for Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I've added a second Master Page to my solution and it's been added with `Page_Load` function by default. I need to add an event `Page_Init` to the code, but right now I can only add it using `Override OnInit`.

Is there a way to add `Page_Init` event ? How can I see the page events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all you should need. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227435.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```